# Thread is creating issue running aaplication in other laptop but works fine in my laptop

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

i have this line of code this method has a thread which is running all the time to check the expiry date comparing with system time

```
Thread expireDateCheckThread;
DataTable _dt;
dbAccess db2;
DataTable _dt2;
public Search()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    db = new dbAccess();
    _dt = new DataTable();
    db2 = new dbAccess();
    _dt2 = new DataTable();
    expireDateCheckThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(checkExpireDate));
    expireDateCheckThread.Start();

}
public void checkExpireDate()
{
    _dt2 = db2.checkExpireDate(DateTime.Now.ToString().Remove(9));
    if (_dt2.Rows.Count != 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _dt2.Rows.Count; i++)
            MessageBox.Show("Serial No: " + _dt2.Rows[i][0].ToString() + "       is Going To Expired");
    }
    Thread.Sleep(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
    checkExpireDate();

}
```

this works fine in my laptop but when i test it in other laptop it showing that application is not working properly

Please help me solve my problem 
thanks in advance

Comment: what is the error. any exceptions?

Comment: Output of `DateTime.Now.ToString()` is culture dependent. I bet regional settings on laptops are different? Look up more details of the error message from Windows Application log.

Comment: when i reached at thread form it says "This program is not working properly"

Comment: If you cannot attach a debugger on that other laptop, install a debug build and retrieve exception details from Windows event log.

Comment: problem occurs immediately after start > culture/region issue or database issue; problem occurs after one day > database connection gone; problem occurs after several years > stack overflow :-)

Comment: I swear i didn't even get u what u r trying to say :D please can u explain in simple way ? :p

Comment: Sure. We need more details. "Application is not working properly" does not help. To find the details, open the Windows Event Log from Control Panel, switch to "Application" and find the error. There will be more information like stack trace, error number. Then we can try to find the source code line that causes the problem.

Comment: hahaha thanks i found the solution it's due to regional time issue Thanks again :p